# Kendo UI Grid grouping - how to set group Title

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo UI Grid with grouping on `RoleName` property. I am trying to set title on the grouped property and can't seem to figure out how to do that.

The view model is below.

```
public class UserMembershipViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    [UIHint("UsersDropdown")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Group")]
    [UIHint("RolesDropdown")]
    public string RoleId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Group")]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

The Kendo Grid is set up as follows.

```
Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.UserName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Email);
        columns.Command(command =>
        {
            command.Destroy();
        }).Title("Actions").Width(200);
    })
    .Editable(editable => editable
                .Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
                .Window(window => window
                    .Title("Add Group Member")
                    .Draggable(true)))
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add Group Member"))
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Groupable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(user => user.UserId);
                model.Field(user => user.UserId).Editable(false);
            })
            .Events(events => events
                .Sync("sync_handler"))
            .Group(group => group.Add(model => model.RoleName))
            .Create(create => create.Action("MembershipCreate", "UserManagement"))
            .Read(read => read.Action("MembershipRead", "UserManagement"))
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("MembershipDestroy", "UserManagement"))
    )
```

And the result is this..

[image: Kendo UI Grid]

The `RoleName` property in view model has `Display` attribute on it. This attribute does work for setting title on column headers (you can see the `Username` column header in the image), but does not work on Group headers.

So the `RoleName` in the image should be `Group`. Any ideas on how to set the group title?

Answer (score 5):

add group field as hidden column with ClientGroupHeaderTemplate:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.RoleName).ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("#=value#").Hidden();
```

Comment: or alternatively use the 'Title' property.